# Importing Shapefile to PostGIS using QGIS DB Manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, database-manager

I am trying to import a shapefile from my QGIS project to my PostGIS schema using DB manager.

I want to create a new table in my public schema and I have an ERROR: relation "spatial_ref_sys" does not exist.

Checking options 'primary key', 'geom column' & 'create spatial index' do not alter the error. Full error message below.

```
Creation of data source "public"."fwamanc" failed: 

Erroneous query: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','fwamanc','geom',27799,'MULTIPOLYGON',2) returned 7

[ERROR:  relation "spatial_ref_sys" does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT SRID         FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE SRID = new_sr...

^

QUERY:  SELECT SRID         FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE SRID = new_srid

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 48 at SQL statement SQL statement "SELECT public.AddGeometryColumn('',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)" PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 5 at SQL statement ]
```

I have already created the postgis extension & checked validity of output.
This is the first time I have tried to import without restoring via pgdump files.

Anybody help with what I may be missing?

Comment: What do you mean with "checked validity of output"?, you run the query?.

Comment: Is PostGIS installed in the public schema?

Answer (score 1):

The user running the query does not have `public` in its path.

The 1st query does not throw a not found error because the path is explicitly written (`SELECT public.AddGeometryColumn ...`)

You can check if the schema where PostGIS is installed is in the user search path by issuing

```
show search_path;
```

If not, you can permanently add the path by altering the user.

```
ALTER USER username SET search_path TO "$user", public;
```

As the previous command takes effect at the next login only, you can apply it immediately by applying

```
SET search_path TO "$user", public;
```